# Override the methods of classes from a .war file

Tags: java

I have a base application war file say homeApp.war.  This contains default operations which user can carry out on the web browser.  Now I need to extend the operations available on the same application using that .war file. Like I need to add the extra menus, some shortcuts like icon for log out etc.  Please let me know how can I use this .war file to extend the operations and also fix the already existing issues on the application.  This web application uses java server faces.

Comment: Do you have full source available or must you tear the WAR apart to change stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can import WAR file.

Deselect all libraries while importing. So all JAR files in WAR file will be added to your project and .class files will be imported. At result you will be able to use WAR file libraries and classes.